# Unable to execute groovy test files in Springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, maven, groovy, spock, spring-boot-test

I have created a sample `SpringBoot` application for writing unit-tests using `Spock` framework. Below are the files.

**Calculator.Java**

```
public class Calculator {
   @Autowired
   Addition addition;

   public int calculate(int a, int b, String choice) {
      return addition.add(a, b);
   }
}
```

I have created test-class using Junit as below, its working fine

**CalculatorTest.java**

```
@SpringBootTest
public class CalculatorTest {

   @Mock
   Addition addition;

   @InjectMocks
   Calculator cal;

   @Test
   public void testCal() {
     when(addition.add(2, 3)).thenReturn(8);
     int value = cal.calculate(2, 3, "add");
     assertEquals(8, value);
   }
}
```

But I need to write unit-test using `Spock Framework`, So I created groovy files and added corresponding `dependencies` and `plugins` in the `pom.xml`. when I run `mvn clean install` to build the application. Under `TESTS` I can see only `CalculatorTest.java` execution but not able to see `CalculatorGroovyTest.groovy` file's execution.

**CalculatorGroovyTest.groovy**

```
@SpringBootTest
class CalculatorGroovyTest extends Specification{

   @Mock
   Addition addition;

   @InjectMocks
   Calculator cal;

   def "Callator test method"(){
       given:
           addition.add(5, 8) --> 9;
       when:
           int val = cal.calculate(5, 8, "add");
       then:
           val == 9;
   }
}
```

Below are the dependencies and Plugins which I added in my pom.

**Dependencies**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-guice</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**PlugIns**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.groovy</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <testSources>
                    <testSource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                        </includes>
                    </testSource>
                </testSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**NOTE:** I am not getting any errors and getting Build Success after maven build

**I am not Sure Why it is not considering `groovy`files for Unit-Testing**

Comment: Would you mind pushing your sample repository to GitHub? I would like to clone and inspect it.

Comment: Any reason you put your groovy files in `${project.basedir}/src/test/java` instead of `${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy`? Furthermore, why do you have an outdated `spock-guice` dependency in a spring project? And `spock-core 1.3-groovy-2.5` needs groovy 2.5 not 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're missing `spock-spring` in your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-groovy-2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I also don't see `spring-boot-starter-test` in that list, please make sure it is there.

Comment: I added `spock-spring` dependency also but it didn't work. `spring-boot-starter-test` was there, it is default dependency so I didn't mention it explicitly.